# What's the time frame that passes in Season 1 of The 100?

Tags: the-100

In Season 1 of *The 100* the heroes are wounded severely, and rise to their feet in no time (or at least it seems so).

I am not able to grasp the time that they spend on earth.

The examples I have are

> Jaspar's been pierced with the spear, and Finn's blade from Lincoln to his chest. Both act normal in the next episode.

How long has passed in these episodes? Wouldn't the air in the Arc, needs to end already?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [official writer's Tumblr account](http://the100writers.tumblr.com/post/108018662568/what-date-does-unity-day-fall-on-id-like-to-know), when asked about a holiday celebrated half way through Season 1:

> **Asked:** What date does Unity Day fall on? I'd like to know so I can party
>
> **Answer:** Chronology questions have been asked a lot (usually in conjunction with ‘has Clarke had her birthday’). I finally was able to get ***the closest thing to an official timeline I can get from our script coordinator Ryan***, who has to keep track of things like how many days/nights pass in an episode.
>
> **According to him, Season 1 was 29 days.** The delinquents **landed on Earth on September 13, 2149**. Unity Day is October 1st.

Considering not all days are shown, and some episode span part of a day while others span multiple days, it's understandable to be confused. The Injuries are the typical [Hollywood Healing](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HollywoodHealing) and [It's only a flesh wound](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OnlyAFleshWound). Jasper recovers from a spear to the chest in a week, ***but they did show SOME signs of complications, infection, drama*** so they didn't just use a reset button. He even has PTSD from it for a while.

Answer (score 4):

Season 1 spanned 29 days, per [the wiki](http://the100.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline). The pilot episode took place on 13 September 2149 and the season finale on 11 October.